# Spring Boot jar launch error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, manifest

Recently I ran `jar` of my `Spring Boot Application`. I've received an error: `no main manifest attribute, in temperaturetracker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar`. I've updated my `build.gradle` so it would contain `Main-Class` attributes, but then I do receive an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at com.example.temperaturetracker.TemperatureTrackerApplication.main(TemperatureTrackerApplication.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more
```

My `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.30-RC'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.example.temperaturetracker.TemperatureTrackerApplication'
        )
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Security
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.5.3'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'

    // springframework
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.5.3'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.0.0'

    // Database
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.23.jre7'

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30-RC'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package com.example.temperaturetracker;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TemperatureTrackerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TemperatureTrackerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Gradle:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip
```

Also hovering over `Main-Class` attribute warning is visible (not sure if this has do to anything with this error):

[image]

Running my app normally by pressing green arrow or (Shift + F10) works normally. I hope someone would be able to solve my issue.

Comment: Do you understand what the exception means?

Comment: Yes. The exception tells me that there is no definition of a class provided by me.

Comment: In the classpath yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-plain.jar` file is a plain jar file without any of Spring Boot’s customizations. This means that it doesn’t contain your application’s dependencies and can’t be launched using `java -jar`.

You need to run `temperaturetracker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is an old thread, but still adding an answer.

Spring Boot will add two jars under build\libs\ (**once we execute ./gradlew clean build or equivalent**) *.jar(this will be jar with all dependencies) and *-plain.jar(will not have any dependencies). Now *-plain.jar is getting picked up and executed and causing **No manifest and Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication (once we fix no manifest by providing manifest under jar {})**.

As Andy confirmed you need to run temperaturetracker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar instead. If we want to stop generating *-plain.jar , we have to simply add following in our build.gradle :

```
jar {
enabled = false
}
```